# Axioms of length

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, curves

Assume I want to define length of plane curves axiomatically.
It seems to be reasonable to assume that

- The length of a unit segment is 1;
- Congruent curves have equal lengths;
- Length is additive with respect to concatenation.

However this is not enuf to define length completely: many different length-like functionals satisfy these properties.

> What would be a complete set of axioms?

**Motivation.** I noticed that many (if not all) proofs of the [Crofton formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crofton_formula) cheat by assuming implicitly that there is a unique length functional that satisfies the above property, which is wrong. The problem is easy to fix, but the proof I see relies on the constructive definition of length; therefore this extra argument has to be repeated in each variation of the Crofton formula, which is not nice.

**P.S.** It seems that the following set of axioms solves the problem (thanks to Taras Banakh):

- The length of any curve is non-negative and invariant with respect to reparametrizations.
- The length of a unit segment is 1;
- Congruent curves have equal lengths;
- Length is additive with respect to concatenation;
- Length is lower semi-continuous with respect to pointwise convergence.

Comment: How would you compute the length of a segment of irrational length?  You could assume length scales in the correct way, but it seems like some sort of approximation hypotheses would be more natural.

Comment: @RBega2, you can assume in addition that length is nonnegative, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: What about replacing additivity by $\sigma$-additivity and adding the condition of semicontinuity: If a sequence of curves $(K_n)$  tends to a curve $K_\infty$ in the Vietoris topology, then $length(K_\infty)\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}length(K_n)$?

Comment: @TarasBanakh Yes, it seems to work --- thank you, it seems that sigma-additivity can be exchanged to positivity. Did you see these axioms somewhere?

Comment: What is wrong just to write that $length(K)=\liminf length(K_\alpha)$ where $(K_\alpha)$ is the net of all possible finite (and connected) unions of segments that converges to $K$ in the Vietoris topology. The invariantness of the length on segments determines it uniquely.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin No I have not seen such axioms before (which does not mean that they are completely new). By the way, it is interesting if such a definition of length coincides with the 1-dimensional Hausdorff measure in the class of compact connected subsets of the plane?

Comment: @TarasBanakh for the inf-def --- it seems to be an other constructive definition, so you can not just say that if two sides of formula satisfy these properties then they are equal.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Here a problem arizes: what is a curve? If it is just a Peano continuum, then the length can be defined as in my answer. But if a curve is a function $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb R^2$, then things became more complicated. For example, what is the length of the curve $\gamma:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$, $\gamma:t\mapsto |t|$? 1 or 2? What is the definition of a segment? Just an affine function? Then we should add an invariance under the change of a parametrization, etc, etc.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin By the way, what are "congruent curves"? Just $\gamma$ and $h\circ\gamma$, where $h$ is an isometry?

Comment: We can define the length of a continuous curve $\gamma$ as the least upper bound of $$\sum_{i=1}^n d(\gamma(x_{i-1}),\gamma(x_i))$$ over all partitions with $$0 = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_{n-1} < x_n = 1.$$  Busemann's Geometry of Geodesics showed that this works in any G-space, so in particular in any Euclidean space.  By comparison with this, I'd find any other definition overly complicated.

Comment: @MattF. You should also add that $\max_i|x_i-x_{i-1}|\to 0$, so it will be the lower limit, not the least upper bound.

Comment: @TarasBanakh, I prefer the definition as I stated it.

Comment: @MattF. Then according to your definition, the length of any curve connecting points $a,b$ is equal to the length of the segment $[a,b]$ (as we can take $x_0=0$ and $x_1=1$).

Comment: @TarasBanakh, that’s why it’s a least upper bound over all partitions; almost any other partition will yield a bigger sum.

Comment: @TarasBanakh yes sure (I mean the def of congruent curves).

Comment: @MattF. You suggest the standard def and it does not solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure it will be related, but when I think of axiomatizations of measurements, I think of the work of Luce and Suppes: https://www.imbs.uci.edu/files/personnel/luce/2002/LuceSuppes_Book%20Chapter_2002.pdf. I'm not sure if they have a section of the case of curves in their three volume set.

Comment: @MattF. You are right: somehow I mixed $\sup$ with $\inf$ in your definition of length.

Comment: You don't have to jump through hoops to get Crofton formulae. You just have to realize what they really do: transform measures into densities: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00029-007-0045-5

Comment: @alvarezpaiva that is right, but it requires some analysis (say you will need Vitali covering theorem which is nice, but not for a geometry course).

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest the following axioms.

The *length* in a metric space $X$ is a function $\ell:c(X)\to[0,+\infty]$ defined on the family $c(X)$ of all connected compact subsets of $X$ that satisfies the following axioms:

1) $\ell$ is *non-degenerated*, which means that a continuum $C\in c(X)$ is a singleton if and only if $\ell(C)=0$;

2) $\ell$ is *monotone*, which means that $\ell(A)\le \ell(B)$ for any  continua $A\subset B$ in $X$;

3) $\ell$ is *additive*, which means that $\ell(A\cup B)=\ell(A)+\ell(B)$ for any continua $A,B\subset X$ with finite non-empty intersection $A\cap B$;

4) $\ell$ is *affine*, which means that 
$\ell(f(C))=\lambda\cdot\ell(C)$ for any continuum $C\subset X$, any $\lambda>0$ and any bijective function $f:X\to X$ such that $d(f(x),f(y))=\lambda \cdot d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$;

5) $\ell$ is *semicontinuous* in the sense that for any $A\in c(X)$  and any $\varepsilon>0$ there a neighborhood $O_A\subset c(X)$ of $A$ in the Vietoris topology such that $\ell(A')\ge \ell(A)-\varepsilon$ for every $A'\in O_A$.

I hope that the following theorem of existence and uniqueness holds:

**Theorem.** In each Euclidean space $E$ there exists a length $\ell$. Moreover, two lengths $\ell,\lambda:c(E)\to[0,+\infty]$ are equal if $\ell([a,b])=\lambda([a,b])$ for some distinct points $a,b\in E$.

In his [survey paper](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=JWyoCRkLFAkC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=Encyclopedia%20of%20General%20topology%20Murat%20Tuncaly) Murat Tuncali writes that the length of continua was studied by Eilenberg, Harrold (1943) and later Buskirk, Nikiel, and Tymchatyn (1992).

Comment: Originally I wanted to find a right way to fix a gap in the standard proof of Crofton formula --- your suggestion seem to be an overkill.